# How to get tweets that contain geolocation information

Tags: twitter, geolocation

Do you know if there is a way to get **only** tweets (using [search/tweets api](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets)) that contains geolocation information?

I want to do a search, 100 tweets, and show in a map all of them. But, in most of my search, there is no more than 1 tweet with geolocation added.

When I say "geolocation" I'm talking about the "coordinates" tweet attribute, because "geo" is deprecated.

Thanks, Noel.